# Post value of md-datepicker back to server

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am playing around with angular and material for a while now (coming from jquery, it was a little bit an effort). I do understand that it is a pure client based thing, but what is the client without server... in my case I have a datepicker which I want to post back to the server and have no idea how to.

So this is my datepicker:

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="user.birthdate" md-placeholder="Birthdate" ng-required="true">
</md-datepicker>
```

It's quite obvious that there is no "name" attribute which would be required to post it.

What I also tried is adding a hidden input field with the same model, but it's also empty on the server:

```
<input type="hidden" name="birthdate" ng-model="user.birthdate" />
```

So my ideas to solve it would be either to write a directive for adding the name to the actual input behind the datepicker (which will cause some issues with the date format) or read the data when submitting it to the server and somehow transfer it with the form (e.g. with the hidden field). But I cannot believe that it is so complicated because I assume that I am not the only one with this requirement - and whenever I search I only find stuff like date format issues...

Thanks in advance,
Philipp

Comment: You are thinking in jQuery  when you should be thinking in Angular. The value for `user.birthdate` should be available in the Controller as either $scope.user.birthdate (if you inject $scope in your controller) or as `this.user.birthdate` (if you use Controller As syntax)

Comment: yes of course, but still, I can't get it to the server. I forgot the third possibility -> ajax, but a postback also has some advantages...

Comment: you can send data by the input field itself but instead of hidden you have to use "display:none" in input style.angular ng-model does not send hidden input values.